# Do Math in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create add calculation in view, it was successfull, but how to create add operation's in controller?

here my code

```
public String jumlah(@RequestParam(value = "a") int angkaPertama, @RequestParam(value = "b") int angkaKedua, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("a", angkaPertama);
        model.addAttribute("b", angkaKedua);
        return "jumlah";
    }
```

And i have one more question
here is my code:

```
<p th:text="'Welcome ' + ${name} + '!'">Good Morning</p>
```

Why "Good Morning" does'nt show up in my view?

Comment: So, you have both numbers in angkaPertama and angkaKedua. You can just do angkaPertama + angkaKedua? and store it in a variable and then add that to model?

Answer (score 0):

Add @ResponseBody  to the return type of method.And i hope you have proper request  mapping for the url of your page.

Comment: then how to put it in view?

Comment: How are you calling controller method.Is it a ajax call.If it is ajax call you can append string response to text.